# WP7 remove app from marketplace means what?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I removed my App from wp7 marketplace, what does it mean?
- app is still available in marketplace but hidden
- app is removed from marketplace
- app is removed and get uninstalled on user devices

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: not a programming question,,, It just gets removed from market place . and not from user devices obviously

Comment: Good point, where would be appropriate to post questions like this?

Comment: googling a little got me `www.wp7forum.com`

Comment: sry, that this seems to be the wrong forum, but this question based on a programming problem ;) - thx for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application will be no longer be available from the marketplace, all records that it once was there will still exist.

Anyone that has it downloaded/purchased will still have the application. As far as it is known there no 'kill switch' available for applications.